# Run a curl command using CRON jobs

Tags: curl, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to run this statement:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import'
```

every 10 minutes using CRON jobs.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like:

```
crontab <<'EOF'
SHELL=/bin/bash
#min hr md mo wkday command
*/10 *  *  *  *     curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import'
EOF
```

Use `crontab -l` to get a look at it afterwards.  *BUT*, add an option to that `curl` command to put the output somewhere specific, since it might be run somewhere to which you don't have write access.  Also, if `curl` is anywhere unusual, you may need to specify its full path, like `/usr/bin/curl`, or set the `crontab` PATH variable.

The quotes around `EOF` prevent substitution in the contents of the HEREIS document (everything between the `<<EOF` and `EOF).  HEREIS documents are a shell feature, not part of`crontab`.

See `man 5 crontab` for a detailed breakdown of what goes in crontab files.

I usually keep a `~/.crontab` file to edit with a special first line, and the execute bit set:

```
#!/usr/bin/env crontab 
SHELL+/bin/sh
[... etc.]
```

This lets me edit my `~/.crontab` and then just run it with:

```
$ vi ~/.crontab
$ ~/.crontab
```

(I also usually have extensions on them to indicate which host they're for, like ~/.crontab.bigbox)

Comment: I like the ~/.crontab suggestion!

Answer (score 8):

In case of using Cpanel :
Cpanel->Cron Jobs->Put Time Interval(*/10 * * * * )
Add command in the text box:
`curl -s "http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import"`
where **-s** stands for silent (no output)
You are done

Answer (score 0):

For blue host and go daddy server:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import"
```