# Running background tasks in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my scenario:

```
1. Scrape some data every X minutes from example.com
2. Insert it to Mongodb database
3. Subscribe for this data in Meteor App.
```

Because, currently I am not very good at Meteor this is what I am going to do:

```
1. Write scraper script for example.com in Python or PHP.
2. Run script every X minutes with cronjob.
3. Insert it to Mongodb.
```

Is it possible to do it completely with Meteor without using Python or PHP? How can I handle task that runs every X minutes?

Answer (score 4):

There are Cron like systems such as [percolate:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) for Meteor. There, you could register a job using [Later.js](http://bunkat.github.io/later/) syntax similar to this example taken from the percolate:synced-cron readme file:

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  }, 
  job: function() {
    var numbersCrunched = CrushSomeNumbers();
    return numbersCrunched;
  }
});
```

If you want to rely on an OS level cron job, you could just provide an HTTP endpoint in your Meteor.js application [that you could then access through curl at the chosen time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850967/run-a-curl-command-using-cron-jobs).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest [Steve Jobs](https://github.com/msavin/SteveJobs..meteor.jobs.scheduler.queue.background.tasks), my new package for scheduling background jobs in Meteor.

You can use the `register`, `replicate`, and `remove` actions

```
// Register the job

Jobs.register({ 
    dataScraper: function (arg) {
        var data = getData()

        if (data) {
            this.replicate({
                in: {
                    minutes: 5
                }
            });

            this.remove(); // or, this.success(data)
        } else {
            this.reschedule({
                in: {
                    minutes: 5
                }
            })
        }
    }
})

// Schedule the job to run on Meteor startup
// `singular` ensures that there is only pending job with the same configuration

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Jobs.run("dataScraper", {
        in: {
            minutes: 5
        }, 
        singular: true
    })
})
```

Depending on your preference, you can store the result in the database, as part of the jobs history, or remove it entirely.