# How I run a cron job in Openshift?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, cron, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I have a docker container in Openshift, this docker have a spring boot microservice that I want to execute only every X minutes.

How I can do it using Openshift?

I don't know how to create a cron job or similar to launch this microservice every X minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't found it already, cron job documentation for OpenShift can be found at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html

Comment: Thanks!, your comment is really good!

Comment: If you go that path with jobs, there are some tricks needed if you want it to use image from an image stream. If get that far let us know and will dig up prior SO question where is explained how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are exposing an http service, you may use a mix between [cron in docker](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/) and [curl with cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850967/run-a-curl-command-using-cron-jobs), you can configure a cron inside your docker container to send a curl request periodically, invoking your microservice.