# Automated Backup in AEM 6.5

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am new to AEM and my lead asked me to find a way to automate the backup process for Author instance in AEM.

So far What I got are AEM workflows. But I am not sure that It would help or how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852939/1514647) to run the following curl command:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/system/console/jmx/com.adobe.granite:type=Repository/op/startBackup/java.lang.String?target=backup.zip
```

This will start the backup job accessible via jmx here: `http://localhost:4502/system/console/jmx/org.apache.jackrabbit.oak%3Aname%3DSegment+node+store+backup%2Frestore%2Ctype%3DFileStoreBackupRestore`

The backup file/directory is created on the server in the parent folder of the folder containing the crx-quickstart folder (the same as if you were creating the backup using the browser).

Check out the [Adobe documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/administering/operations/backup-and-restore.html?lang=en) for more info regarding Online and Offline Backups.